# Any singular matrix is similar to a matrix of form $\begin{pmatrix}B&\\&0\end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, similar-matrices

> Any singular matrix $A$ is similar to a matrix of form $\begin{pmatrix}B&\\&0\end{pmatrix}$, where $B$ is a matrix with rank $r$?

Is this right? that is, is there exists an invertible matrix $P$, such that $P^{-1}AP=\begin{pmatrix}B&\\&0\end{pmatrix}$, with $rank B=r$.

$B$ may not be a $r\times r$ matrix? Or may we assume $B$ is $r\times r$?

As is well known, invertible $P,Q$ exists such that $PAQ=\begin{pmatrix}I_r&\\&0\end{pmatrix}$. Does this help?

Comment: No. Consider any invertible matrix $A$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I have added "singular".

Comment: I don't know much algebra; I am just guessing. Consider the nilpotent matrices with maximum order of nilpotency. Can you bring $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ or $\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$ to your proposed form by conjugating with an invertible matrix? I doubt that cuz they are already in Jordan normal form.

Comment: As noted by @Nothingspecial the conclusion implies that $A$ has at least two eigenvectors (complex valued), which is not true in general.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. What is $r$? Is it a prespecified quantity? If $r$ is just a notation for $\operatorname{rank}(B)$, the answer to your question is obviously affirmative: just pick a basis where the basis vectors in the back are those for $\ker(A)$. If $r$ means the rank of $A$, then the answer is negative in general, as pointed out by the others in some comments above.